# RavenDB NserviceBus for multiple Endpoints

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I have multiple Endpoints with one MVC web project. 
How should I use RavenDB ?

I want to keep one saga project as endpoint and multiple other endpoints.
No other endpoints need persistence except Saga project because, Saga project is the process controller and it has to store Sagadata. It will manage the process and update the SagaData for that I want to use RavenDB to store sagadata.

However, for each endpoint I believe have to setup persistence and unnecessary I have to instantiate datastore and put it for each endpoint is it correct ?

Which option I should pick EmbededRavenDB or RavenDB hosted in IIS?

I want to use EmbededRavenDB since it doesnot need port to be open in server. 
I think Server Deployment wise it will be easy. Is it true ?

For each endpoint do I have to recreate the document store instance while configuring bus ? I am not clear how to manage database across the endpoints.

Do we have any sample ?
How should I proceed ? Any thoughts!

Comment: I am using IIS hosted RAVEN DB, How should I share the DocumentStore across the endpoints. If I keep instantiating same document store for all of the endpoints then I am not able to send message from SAGA to any endpoint getting error: `NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver Failed to process message System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException  0x8004D102): A resource manager with the same identifier is already registered with the specified transaction coordinator.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653715/a-resource-manager-with-the-same-identifier-is-already-registered-with-the-speci

Answer (score 0):

I am using 6 Endpoints and for each endpoint I am instantiating new document store for ravendb by applying unique resourcemanagerid for each one. However, I wish I could have used Embeded RavenDB but I am not sure how should I use embeded with 6 endpoints and one MVC project. Which one will be server where should I put DATA folder lots of question I have.

As of now my development is good not sure how will do setup in server with NServicebus using Ravendb IIS hosted one.

Comment: I would install RavenDB as a service and have all you endpoints/processes use a single data store for persistence. (an endpoint is a process hosting NServiceBus handlers)

Comment: Hi Sean, I am also doing the same thing,. I have RavenDB installed as IIS  server and all of my endpoints points to the same RavenDB server. While configuring endpoints persistence, they instantiate the DocumentStore which points to the hosted RavenDB server in IIS. pretty much same. The only concern I had, each end point while configuring instantiates the ravendb data-store with their unique resourcemanagerid.